# mysql all queries are not working in php same file

Tags: php, mysql

i need to run three php MySQL query in one file but two works at a time but not all three are working. I run them separately they work. I used concatenation too but still didn't works.

i tried concatination by applying commas and . before equal sign still, it didn't helps

two queries are executing at a time but not three are executing i used commas and dots too but it also didn't helped.
i dont know here the problem is why all queries are not working in a single php file

```
    <?php
    include 'databaseconfig.php';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $Emails =  $_GET['email'];
    $Cards =  $_GET['card'];
    $Table =  $_GET['table'];
    $Token_key=$_GET['Token_key'];
    $Bet_amount=$_GET['Bet_amount'];
    //1st query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Game_table (Email,Card_no,Table_no,Token_key,Bet_amount)
    VALUES ('$Emails', '$Cards', '$Table', '$Token_key', '$Bet_amount')";
//2nd query
      $sql .= " UPDATE LaborRegistered SET balance = balance - '$Bet_amount' WHERE Phone_no ='$Emails';";



    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";


        sleep(10);
        include 'push_notification.php';

        function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
        {
            $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
            $fields = array(
                 'registration_ids' => $tokens,
                 'data' => $message
                );

            $headers = array(
                'Authorization:key = AIzaSyDAep_Hxa8iY5FxvlDKF1e_9Ws9EUhFCEw ',
                'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

           $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
          $result = curl_exec($ch);           
          if ($result === FALSE) {
              die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
          }
          curl_close($ch);
          return $result;
        }



    //3rd query
        $sql .= " Select Token_key From Game_table";
    //this is not working
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $tokens = array();

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $tokens[] = $row["Token_key"];
            }
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    //sending notification
        $message = array("message" => " FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TEST MESSAGE");
        $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
        echo $message_status;


         return 1;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        return 0;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

my php file should execute all of the queries

Comment: Please use prepared statements. You’ll lose your server within weeks to any kid.

Comment: and how to run all queries sir?

Comment: You miss ; after first query

Comment: `mysqli_query()` can't run multiple queries at once.

Comment: Use error_reporting(E_ALL) after <?php so you could see what error you are facing

Comment: I would look into using [transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) instead. Then you can rollback all changes if any of the queries fail.

Comment: Have you considered writing a stored procedure?  Stored procedures are great for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` can execute only one query at once. If you want to execute many queries you have to use [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Note that your queries have to be separated by a semi column.

In example

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Game_table (Email,Card_no,Table_no,Token_key,Bet_amount)
    VALUES ('$Emails', '$Cards', '$Table', '$Token_key', '$Bet_amount');";
//2nd query            Notice this ------------------------------------^
$sql .= " UPDATE LaborRegistered SET balance = balance - '$Bet_amount' WHERE Phone_no ='$Emails';";

if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === true)
{
    // ...
}
```

Concerning the return value, the documentation states :

> Returns **FALSE** if the first statement failed. To retrieve subsequent errors from other statements you have to call [mysqli_next_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php) first.

---

Please consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with [parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to bind user's input datas to the queries. They are actually vulnerables to [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).